# Drag&drop of a local file does not work under Ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qml

I have a list of local files in my app. I'm trying to add the functionality to drag and drop them to arbitrary location on the file system (e.g. drag&drop from my app to Files app).

All is working fine under Windows and macOS.

Ubuntu - does not work (nothing happens). I suspect there is something to do with the `Drag.mimeData`.

Example of the code I'm using:

```
Item
{
    id: root

    property string fileUrl: "file:///home/user/Downloads/index.html"

    Drag.active: mouseArea.drag.active
    Drag.mimeData: {"text/uri-list": root.fileUrl}
    Drag.dragType: Drag.Automatic

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        drag.target: root
    }
}
```

**Addition #1**. I was using `Qt 5.12.12`. Tested under `Qt 6.4.1` - works fine now. Instead of two things:

1. It seems it copies files instead of moving them.
2. Drag&drop to Desktop does not work. Workaround: open Files app, open Desktop location there, and then d&d from my app to the Files app.